# Is there a cryptographic solution for this “dating protocol”?

Tags: protocol-design, zero-knowledge-proofs

The article [Cryptographic Protocols with Everyday Objects](http://www.computing.surrey.ac.uk/personal/st/S.Schneider/papers/2011/cryptoforma11a.pdf) by James Heather, Steve Schneider, and Vanessa Teague describes the following **dating protocol** (due to Bert den Boer):

> Alice and Bob wish to determine
>   whether they both want to go on a date; but they want to avoid the embarrassing
>   situation in which one of them does not want to go on a date, but knows that the
>   other would have liked to do so. Essentially they need a two-player veto protocol:
>   they want to compute whether at least one has vetoed the date, without revealing
>   any further information.

**Q:** Bennett’s solution uses playing cards. Does this problem admits cryptographic solution?

Of course it can be reduced to [Yao's Millionaires' Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yao%27s_Millionaires%27_Problem). But probably this problem has a simpler solution.

Comment: What you need is a secure two party computation protocol to compute an AND.

Comment: You can reduce it to socialist millionaires, which is pretty simple.

Comment: I'm surprised to see the dating protocol attributed to Charles Bennett, because it is known as Bert den Boer's five card trick. Den Boer used it as a very nice and playful introduction to his Eurocrypt '89 about MPC protocols for match-making. However, Bennett is acknowledged by Claude Crépeau and Joe Kilian in their Crypto '93 paper "Discreet Solitary Games," which is about card-based MPC protocols for the Secret Santa problem. So Bennett was a bit into these protocols as well, and probably liked Den Boer's five-card trick a lot.

Comment: @BerrySchoenmakers Thank you for the information about Bert den Boer's article. Indeed, I took the information from "Discreet Solitary Games".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a protocol solving the [Socialist millionaires problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_millionaires) for this. Socialist millionaires compares two integers for equality. There are relatively simple implementations of this protocol, similar to Diffie-Hellman, which are used to implement PAKE (password authenticated key-exchange).

Agree a fixed integer to denote `true`. A party chooses that value if they want to signal `true` and a random other value (say 256-bits) if they want to signal `false`. This clearly works for the case where at least one party chooses `true`. If both parties choose `false` it will almost certainly produce a not-equal result from SM, since the chance of two random values being equal is negligible.

Thus you can securely implement the AND function using a Socialist millionaires protocol.

Answer (score 4):

First agree on a large prime $p$, a generator $g$, and a random value module $p$ to represent $true$.  Each party has their choice of date or not as $C_{a,b} \in \{0,1\}$.  Then each party $i$ computes:

$ \\
false \leftarrow random() \\
k_{private} \leftarrow random() \\
choice_i \leftarrow H(true \times C_i + false \times (1 - C_i)) \\
e \leftarrow g^{choice_i \times k_{private}} \\
\text{Send } e_i \text{ to the other player, receiving } e_{\bar{i}} \\
\text{Publish } e_{\bar{i}}^{k_{private}}
$

This is just a typical private set intersection specialized to a single element.

Comment: This doesn't seem secure. Even if I vote false. I still know if you voted true or not.

Comment: Claiming you know and showing the math are two different things.  Care to show how?  This is a typical protocol.  I sent $g^{ck_a}$ and you don't have $k$.   You can get me to compute $g^{ck_ak_b}$ but then your $c$ must be 'true' and revealing the result of an _and_ operation is the whole point.

Comment: I take it back, I was confusing choice for Ci

Comment: What is `H` function here?

Comment: Just a hash function. SHA512 if you'd like.