# Unanimity for three (or more) players

Tags: protocol-design, zero-knowledge-proofs

The article [Cryptographic Protocols with Everyday Objects](http://www.computing.surrey.ac.uk/personal/st/S.Schneider/papers/2011/cryptoforma11a.pdf) by James Heather, Steve Schneider, and Vanessa Teague describes the following **unanimity protocol for three players**:

> Three players want to determine whether they all agree on the
>   point at issue; if they do not all agree, then they will not discover who stands
>   alone against the other two. This is useful in situations where eventual consensus is required, but there is a danger that voters might be unduly influenced by knowledge of the other votes.

**Q:** The given solution uses playing cards. What is the most natural cryptographic solution of this problem? (Hopefully it will work for more players.)

The secure two-party computation of logical AND from the same article was discussed at [Is there a cryptographic solution for this “dating protocol”?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55504/is-there-a-cryptographic-solution-for-this-dating-protocol).

Comment: It may be helpful, to realize that this is a secure multi-party computation of a three-input AND.

Comment: @SEJPM It is not exactly AND. It is $(abc)OR(\bar a\bar b\bar c).$